# How do I post a message to confirm a sent message after a page redirect (C#/ASP.Net)

Tags: c#, asp.net, smtp, response.redirect

Hi I've just set up a method in my website to send an email from a Contact Us page, I wanted to clear the asp.net form of all of the email details once they have sent the email so I've used a response.redirect to refresh the page as such. I want to display a message or a pop up window to show that the message has been sent, but because the page is being refreshed the label I am trying to write this to never gets called. Is there any way around this or a way to clear the form without a redirect? Here is the code I am working with:

```
protected void SubmitBtn_Click(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
    MailMessage mailObj = new MailMessage(
       EmailTxt.Text, "xxxxx@xxxxx.com", SubjectTxt.Text, MessageTxt.Text);
    SmtpClient SMTPServer = new SmtpClient("localhost");
    try
    {
        SMTPServer.Send(mailObj);
        Response.Redirect("ContactMe.aspx");
        base.OnLoad(e);
        MessageLbl.Text = "Email Sent SucessFully.";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageLbl.Text = ex.ToString();
    }
}
```

Many Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Response.Redirect` is your problem. You are effectively refreshing the page and any code after that is irrelevant. Why not just clear the form via clode (i.e. `myTextBox.Text = string.Empty` etc. and then set the message text?

```
try
{
    SMTPServer.Send(mailObj);
    // Clear email form
    Control1.Text = string.Empty;
    Control2.Text = string.Empty;
    // etc...
    MessageLbl.Text = "Email Sent SucessFully.";
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageLbl.Text = ex.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't want your user left on the email page (assuming you want to take them somewhere else after they send their email) you could use:

```
Response.AddHeader("REFRESH","3;URL=yourURL.aspx");
```

Instead of

```
Response.redirect.
```

Your label will pop up with the message and then the redirect will happen a few seconds later.